# Touch not detectable past Panel - Unity3D/Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch, vuforia, gameobject

I have been trying to add touch event to 3D gameObject in Unity.
Previously I was not using any Canvas or Panel so by using Event Trigger and Event System I was able to add touch events to the Gameobject but then I wanted to use a UI for Application and implemented this hierarchy.

1. Camera
2. GameOBject
3. Canvas
    Panel(Transparent)
       -Buttons
    Panel2 
    EventSystem

So if i tap a part it does not respond.

Camera does have Physics Raycaster.
Gameobjects have colliders and mesh renderers.

I want a touch input from the mobile device.

Thanks

Comment: Since you have a Raycast, check what it hits.

Comment: It shoud hit GameObject parts

Comment: There is what it should hit and there is what it does hit. So what does it hit? Is it what you expect or is something else happening?

Answer (score 1):

If two Button overlap each other then the order in which camera renders top will be detected.
So try changing the hierarchy  order (remember the last in the hierarchy is always top of the camera  ) you can achieve which one to click

---

Comment: Button are not overlapping rather they are on corners and my panel is transparent with sprite raycast target unchecked.

Comment: can u upload the screenshot of hierarchy ?

Comment: Thanks i figured it out what was causing this